# Binding an element of a UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I've created a UserControls called SimpleText and referenced it in my MainWindow.xaml. The only thing that is in my SimpleText is a TextBox (called tbox). In my MainWindow there is another TextBox (called tbox2). What I want to achieve is to have a TwoWay binding between that two text boxes.

I've read here in stackoverflow that for changing something internally you must to declare a property in the code of the UserControls (correct me if this is not needed):

```
 public string MyText
        {
            get { return tboxUser.Text; }
            set { tboxUser.Text = value; }
        }
```

Then I can access MyText from MainWindow.xaml but only can give it "static" values:

```
Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication11"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!-- <local:SimpleText MyText="Hello"/>  Works !-->
        <local:SimpleText MyText="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbox2}"/> <!--Does not work-->
        <TextBox x:Name="tbox2" Margin="0,200,0,0"  Text="Text Box 2" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It gives me an error saying this:

A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'MyText' property of type 'SimpleText'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

But sadly I've very newbie here and I have no idea how to make MyText a DependencyProperty. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ripped from http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/c/create-dependencyproperty-dependencyobject-5-minutes/

public int Age
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(AgeProperty); } //do NOT modify anything in here
        set { SetValue(AgeProperty, value); } //...or here
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Age.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AgeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Age",  //Must be the same name as the property created above
        typeof(int), //Must be the same type as the property created above
        typeof(Person), //Must be the same as the owner class
        new UIPropertyMetadata(
            0,  //default value, must be of the same type as the property
            new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>  //A callback that gets executed when the property changed
            {
                var source = s as Person;
                s.DOB_Year = DateTime.Now.Year - s.Age; 
            })));
```

for your case, it would be something like below (note the frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.bindstwowaybydefault).  i didnt actually test this, so not sure if syntax is right of it works, but its the general idea

```
public string MyText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); } //do NOT modify anything in here
    set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                              MyTextPropertyChangedCallback));

private static void MyTextPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var source = d as SimpleText;
    source.MyText = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

**Update**

I tried recreating with this simple example and noticed the same thing you were in the comment.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325911/A-Simple-Pattern-for-Creating-Re-useable-UserContr) provided some more in depth explanation.  Towards the bottom of the article it describes how the data context for your user control is inherited from the parent.  You won't see errors at compile time, but if you [turn on wpf tracing for data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx), you would notice data binding errors in your output console.  The fix is to adjust the data context inside your user control, which can be done a couple of ways, but easiest is probably in the constructor, set the data context on the top level UI element in your xaml (grid or stack panel or whatever) to itself.

```
public SimpleText()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid.DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but although the compiler throws no error, the binding doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: I finally could set a binding by adding that DataContext reference and the other thing I was missing: binding IN my UserControl XAML textbox to MyText property. Now I have a strange behaviour: if I write in the MainWindow TextBox (tbox2) it updates automatically, but not if I write in the UserControl Textbox (tbox), I have to click in the other Textbox to make the change happen. Has it something to do with the INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Ok, here is the solution of my last problem: Text="{Binding ElementName=miControl, Path=MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". I think the default way is updating when the control loses focus (that's why when I clicked the other TextBox the value updated).

Comment: Yup. Default behavior is updating when focus changes. You got that part right.